# Solr suggest - method for populating a dictionary file based on prior successful searches

Tags: solr

I am working on providing auto-suggest functionality in our search application (which uses Solr) based on terms used in previous successful searches. In the Solr suggest documentation (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester), I see how to do this using a dictionary file.  My question is:  Does Solr have any utilities for populating a dictionary file, or do I need to write my own?

I haven't found utilities for doing this in the Solr documentation.  But before I started to write my own job to build the dictionary file, I figured it's worth asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

We had a Similar requirement for providing auto suggest on popular searches.
Solr did not provide and out of the box solution for the searches, it does provide it based on the Index or dictionary based.
You can use Solr Suggester and build an new index with the successful Searches and have suggestion based on it.

Else you would need to build up a custom solution for searches with popularity.

What we tried was -

- Building an index with the searches and their count and providing autosuggest based on it.
- We didn't wanted to maintain the count, and the overhead to maintain and increment it, so we indexed all the Successful search terms multiple times as they were being searched upon.
- We used the [Terms Component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) as it provides a terms.prefix option to get the auto suggest feature and as the terms are returned based on the frequency that took care of the popularity.
- As the field being used for terms were only marked indexed and not stored, the index size did not grew considerably with same terms being pushed multiple times.